# Using Timers for scheduling

Tags: timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I am working on a project where I need to run more than one process simultaneously. I tried using threads but I have a problem using it as I am using remote API and have problems with opening ports. So I want to use timers to schedule these processes.

**for example:**

- task1 for *500 ms*
- then pause
- task 2 for *500 ms*
- then pause
- task3 *500 ms*,
- then repeat the cycle *again until all tasks are finished.*

Comment: What language?  What do ports have to do with any of this?  Is there a question in there?  This "question" is just you posting your design idea, it seems.  (And btw, multiple threads do sound like the way to go, instead of re-implementing multitasking inside a single thread.)

Comment: It is unclear what issues exactly you had with threading and ports. Maybe raise that first as reinventing Threading will not be ideal. Rephrase the question and be very clear were you need assistanc.

Comment: I am using java, I am connecting eclipse to a simulation program called V-rep by remote API , Threading is the best solution I know but there is a problem in connection multiple thread. So I am trying to make a simple schedule myself , but can't find a timer that control a duration of a process .